# What is the current status of placing chiral gauge theories in a lattice? Can we place the SM in a lattice?

Tags: standard-model, lattice-model

Schwartz's book on Quantum Field Theory states in Section 25.5:

> There are enormous practical difficulties with lattice simulations, and many open theoretical questions (such as how to simulate chiral gauge theories).

The book came out 10 years ago, what is the current status on simulating chiral gauge theories, like the SM, in a lattice?